# Authentication in Firebase via socket

Tags: sockets, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, microcontroller

I want to authenticate the access of a microcontroller to Firebase through a wifi module. The wifi module allows me to open a socket to send and receive information through it.

What should I send over the socket so I can authenticate myself?

I'm using small microcontrollers, I can not use C ++ or anything high level. I need to know the bare metal commands that the socket accepts.

Example:

When security is disabled, I can read the database by sending:

```
GET /.json HTTP / 1.1

Host: test-http.firebase.com
```

What do I need to add in order to access using an email address and password?

What is the command to get a ID Token?

Answer (score 0):

You can make authentication calls to the Firebase database using a [REST  API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth). Assuming you are actually able to dispatch HTTP commands from your environment ;-)

Comment: I can not find a list of commands accepted by the server. I do not know what the command is to request the Token ID.